# kivy VirtualMachine for python for android gives (initramfs) udev97 : timeout killing '/sbin/blkid -o udev -p /dev/sda1' [188]

Tags: android, python, kivy

I am new to kivy module and learnt that to compile a Kivy app for android on a virtual box is provided with all requisite software installed.

I have done the following:

1. Downloaded the Kivy_Python_for_android.7z from https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=0B1WO07-OL50_bTR0SElrLTZGWEU
2. Extracted the file Kivy_Python_for_android.vdi
3. Downloaded a Oracle VM VirtualBox v3.2.6
4. Created a virtual machine pointing it to Kivy_Python_for_android.vdi image and started machine

However when machine starts it gives following error again and again :

```
(initramfs) udev97 : timeout killing '/sbin/blkid -o udev -p /dev/sda1' [188]
```

As per documentation on http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html there should be a directory named, *distribution* on the virtual image but I can't find any. Also Python was not installed on it. Please advice.

Comment: Why are you using such an ancient version of VirtualBox? Current version is 4.3.8. VirtualBox 3.2.6 is about 4 years old.

Comment: @broush On installing 4.3.8 it works . So issue was with old version of Virtual box . Thanks